# is AWS Glue PCI DSS compliant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pci-dss

I'm new to the PCI world, but need to research ETL (extract-transform-load) solutions for my team to move data from one place to another. I looked in amazon's [list of PCI DSS compliant resources](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/services-in-scope/), and I noticed Glue is not there. Does this mean Glue should not be used when there is a need for PCI DSS compliance? or does it not need to be because its not storing data, just transforming the data and loading data into an RDS data store?

UPDATE: Glue is now PCI-compliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the **PCI** tab in *[AWS Services in Scope by Compliance Program](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/services-in-scope/)*  Glue **is not** PCI compliant.

I'm not an auditor but I assume processing credit card data on non-PCI-compliant service is not permitted, even if it's not stored there. I guess in cases like this **better be safe than sorry** and **use only compliant services** to cover your back side.

That's what I would do anyway ;)

Comment: thanks. I saw and referenced that same list. I was hoping to see it there without a check mark. but it was completely absent making me question whether this was just an out-of-date list or if glue just isn't compliant. But I agree on erring on the side of caution. If I can't get a definitive answer, I won't use it.

Comment: You are correct. I have confirmation from the paid AWS technical support:

>>>
Regarding the first question, as you have correctly pointed out from the docs Glue and Data pipeline service are not yet PCI compliant. I regret the inconvenience that this may cause and I am afraid that I cannot provide an ETA when these services will be PCI compliant.

Comment: UPDATE: In case you missed Aleksi's answer, Glue is now PCI compliant and on the list I linked in the original question

Answer (score 2):

Just to update anyone else wandering in here: At least at the time of writing Glue *is* PCI compliant, as per [AWS' own documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/services-in-scope/PCI/). The page I linked lists all AWS services which are in PCI scope, and AWS Glue is among them.

Comment: please share the relevant details as a citation and use the link as a reference, in the current point, it may answer the question but it is just an link only answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I commented a bit more on what's behind the link, but it is literally a list of PCI compliant AWS services maintained by AWS itself, and the only thing to cite about AWS Glue there is a checkmark.

Comment: Glue is a fairly simple ETL product. Glue has detection tools for sensitive data. Which is fairly attractive on its own. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/aws-glue-entity-level-actions-sensitive-data/